# PYMC3 Multivariate (matrix) GLM

Tags: matrix, pymc3

My question is: is it possible to use Matrix algebra to specify multivariate models in PYMC3? I give below a real example, which essentially reduces to a multivariate GLM.

I'm trying to implement a state-space model from "Bayesian Econometrics" (Koop 2003 Chapter 8.2.3), **using matrix algebra**. The model is reproduced below, both in expanded form and in matrix form:

[image: ar 1 model]

Note that while this looks quite elaborate, **if you ignore *y* and just consider the equation for *alpha*, this is simply a multivariate GLM with two regressors**.

The problem I'm having is that PYMC3 doesn't appear to like putting stochastic objects in an ndarray, then doing matrix calculations. The following (incomplete -as I haven't defined *y* yet) bit of code doesn't run:

```py
with ar_model:
    from pymc3 import Gamma,Normal,MvNormal

    Tau = dip.size - 4                                  # T i.e. number of samples. The var 'T' is used twice in that chapter.
    T = eye(2)                                          #T_t is a p x p matrix of known constants (pg. 198)
    h = Gamma("h",alpha=0.5,beta=0.5)                   #Prior on pg. 201, "Implies 95% of errors are less than 2%"
    epsilon = Normal("epsilon",mu=0.,tau=h)             #Defn pg. 200 under eq 8.52
    Gamma("lmbda_2",alpha=0.5,beta=0.5)])               #Top of pg. 201
    u = MvNormal("u",mu=zeros(2), tau=h*eye(2),shape=2) #Defn pg. 200 under eq 8.52
    alpha = empty(shape=(Tau,2),dtype="object")
    alpha[0] = [100.,1.]
    for t in range(Tau-1):                                #First line pg. 201
        alpha[t+1] = MvNormal("alpha_%05i" % (t+1), mu = T.dot(alpha[t]) + u, tau = h*eye(2),shape=2)
        # and defn for y would go here ...
```

I get the following error:

```
Applied log-transform to h and added transformed h_log to model.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AsTensorError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-db85604c08d8> in <module>()
     12     alpha[0] = [100.,1.]
     13     for t in range(Tau-1):                                #First line pg. 201
---> 14         alpha[t+1] = MvNormal("alpha_%05i" % (t+1), mu = T.dot(alpha[t]) + u, tau = h*eye(2),shape=2)

C:\Users\ljoublanc\local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\var.pyc in __radd__(self, other)
    232     # ARITHMETIC - RIGHT-OPERAND
    233     def __radd__(self, other):
--> 234         return theano.tensor.basic.add(other, self)
    235 
    236     def __rsub__(self, other):

C:\Users\ljoublanc\local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.pyc in __call__(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
    609         """
    610         return_list = kwargs.pop('return_list', False)
--> 611         node = self.make_node(*inputs, **kwargs)
    612 
    613         if config.compute_test_value != 'off':

C:\Users\ljoublanc\local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\elemwise.pyc in make_node(self, *inputs)
    541         using DimShuffle.
    542         """
--> 543         inputs = list(map(as_tensor_variable, inputs))
    544         shadow = self.scalar_op.make_node(
    545             *[get_scalar_type(dtype=i.type.dtype).make_variable()

C:\Users\ljoublanc\local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\basic.pyc in as_tensor_variable(x, name, ndim)
    206         except Exception:
    207             str_x = repr(x)
--> 208         raise AsTensorError("Cannot convert %s to TensorType" % str_x, type(x))
    209 
    210 # this has a different name, because _as_tensor_variable is the

AsTensorError: ('Cannot convert [100.0 1.0] to TensorType', <type 'numpy.ndarray'>)
```

Is this supported, or am I doing something incorrect? I've noticed that if I execute the final bit of the trace manually (`import theano; as_tensor_variable([100.,10.]`) this appears to work fine, so not sure what's going on here. Also tried replacing the alpha[0] IC with an ndarray `array([100.,10.])`, that doesn't help either.